# O que significa esse caractere ^ nas dependências do package.json?

Tags: node.js

O que significa esse caractere  ^ na versão das dependências do package json ? Qual é a utilidade ? O que vai mudar no meu projeto com isso ?

```
   { "name": "", "description": "", "version": "1.2.3", "devDependencies": { "coffee-script": "^1.6.3" }, "scripts": { "prepare": "" }, "main": "" }
```

Comment: Alguma versão a partir da 1.6.3 porém que não quebre compatibilidade (normalmente, aceita troca até do `minor`, mas não do `major`; não sei o caso específico do `node` entretanto)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O acento circunflexo indica intervalo de versão que não quebre compatibilidade. 
Permite alterações que não modificam o primeiro dígito diferente de zero na versão Abaixo seguem exemplos de intervalo de versão e ao lado o seu significado expandido.

- `^3.1.4` == `>=3.1.4 e <4.0.0`
- `^0.4.2` == `>=0.4.2 e <0.5.0`
- `^0.0.2` == `>=0.0.2 e <0.0.3`